# Apply filters to any or a certain many-to-many record

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filters

Consider these models:

```
from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Person(models.Model):
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField()
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)
```

and the DRF views

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter, OrderingFilter

from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from .serializers import GroupSerializer
from ..models import Group

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all().distinct()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
                       SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = GroupFilter
```

A group can have 0,1,2 or more `Person`s, with 1 and 2 being the most common and where these 1 and 2 are clearly defined. Think of it as Facebook's chat: you have one-on-one chat most commonly, but sometimes you can have a group chat. When is one-one-one chat, 1 is sender, 2 is receiver.

I need to filter these records from DRF, when browsing the `GroupViewSet` and filter by `Person` attributes, where I can apply a group of filters to any `Person` or a certain `Person`.

For any person, no matter to which a certain condition is applied, is clear:

`/api/group/?person__height__gt=100&person__weight__gt=200`

But for a certain person, where a group of conditions apply to that person, in the URL, I could have something like:

`/api/group/?person__0__height__gt=100&person__0__weight__gt=200&person__1__height__lte=200`

And declare these into my custom `FilterSet`:

```
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP

class GroupFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    person__0__height = filters.NumberFilter(method='person_filter')
    person__0__height__gt = filters.NumberFilter(method='person_filter')
    person__0__height__lt = filters.NumberFilter(method='person_filter')
    # ... and so on for the rest of the possibilities 

    def person_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        m2mfield, index, field, *comparison = name.split(LOOKUP_SEP, 3)
        # do subqueries based on the above and construct queryset filter.
```

But as you can imagine, this implies that I'll have a lot of boilerplate code. In my real models there are many fields and the above "solution" seems hacky to me.

So the question is: is there an easier/cleaner way to achieve the above filtering?

Maybe by dynamically declaring the `person__0__height__gt` attributes, for which I couldn't yet find a solution.

Note that I do not know the IDs of the `Person` entities upfront. Those person__0, person__1 are array indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for cleaning code :

```
class GroupFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
      person_range = django_filters.NumericRangeFilter(field_name='person__0__height', lookup_expr='range')
      person = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='person__0__height', lookup_expr='exact')

    class Meta:
          model = Group
          fields = ('person_range','person',)
```

and call with url like this :
127.0.0.1:8000/yourpath/?person=180&person_range_min=130&person_range_max=210

Comment: Thank you, that simplified my code a lot. I still ended up having to pass a `method` param, as that `person__0__height` doesn't actually pick the element with index 0, so I have to do it manually.

Still wish there was a way to dynamically declare these fields.